# The double integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty} A(x+y)^2 e^{-(x+y)}\, dx \,dy$

Tags: integration

I met this double integral while reviewing calculus,

the equation is like:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty} A(x+y)^2 e^{-(x+y)} dxdy=1$$

and we should find the value of $A$ by doing the integral,

I tried to change coordinate into polar, namely, let $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=r\sin{\theta}$, but we can see the upper limit of $x$ is infinity, so there is definitely no such $r$ that satisfied this condition.

Then I tried to first integrate over variable $x$ (treat $y$ as constant first), but also find this method not very convenient,

so any idea how to do this integral? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expand the square, and you have the sum of  $3$ easy to compute integrals.

Comment: If I understand what you mean correctly(assume you are not neglecting the exp^(x+y) term, the expansion will result in a really really long equation, is it? @Kelenner

Comment: I know for $b<0$, $$\int _0^1 x^a e^{-x^b}=-\frac{\Gamma (\frac{1+a}{b},1)}{b}$$ where $\Gamma$ is incomplete gamma function, so replace the variable $x\to \frac{1}{x}$, and express the integral with $\Gamma$ function, and use the numerical result of $\Gamma$ will get the answer, I think.

Comment: neglecting the factor $A$, you have your integral equal to $ \int\int x^2\exp(-x)\exp(-y)dxdy+2\int\int xy\exp(-x)\exp(-y)dxdy+\int\int y^2\exp(-y)\exp(-x)dxdy$. Each of these integral is of the form $\int\int f(x)g(y)dxdy=(\int f(x)dx)(\int g(y)dy)$ (I have not written the interval of integration).

Comment: @Alexis This is the first time I see using gamma function in this way, so since your replaced x+y with a new variable, say u, then I wondering about does this mean the dxdy is automatically diminished so we don't have to consider this term anymore? Otherwise I'm thinking about the dxdy term...since d(x+y)=dx+dy

Comment: Yes, it boils down to repetitive integration by parts.

Comment: @Kelenner Ah, I see, I think this is called the separation of variables :)

Comment: Yes. And to find the one dimensional integrals involved, you can compute $\int_1^{+\infty}\exp(-x)dx$, and when computed, re-calculate it by parts (integrate $1$, derive $\exp(-x)$) to find $\int_1^{+\infty}x\exp(-x)dx$, etc..;

Comment: @Kelenner $$\int_{1}^{\infty}x e^{-x}dx=\int_{1}^{\infty}-x d(e^{-x})=-x(e^{-x})-\int e^{-x}d(-x)$$...etc

Comment: @Catherine Chen Yes, something like that.

Comment: @Kelenner good :)

Comment: I think I mean let $X=\frac{1}{x},Y=\frac{1}{y}$ $$A\int _1^{\infty}dx\int _1^{\infty}dy(x+y)^2 e^{-x}e^{-y}\\=A\int _0^1 X^{-2}dX\int_0^1Y^{-2}dY(\frac{1}{X^2}+2\frac{1}{XY}+\frac{1}{Y^2})e^{-X^{-1}}e^{-Y^{-1}}\\=A\int _0^1 dY (\Gamma(3,1)Y^{-2}+2\Gamma(2,1)Y^{-3}+\Gamma(1,1)Y^{-4})e^{-Y^{-1}}\\=A(2\Gamma(3,1)\Gamma(1,1)+2\Gamma(2,1)\Gamma(2,1))=1$$ But I actually looked up the incomplete gamma function, it turn out that, it is defined as $$\Gamma(s,x)=\int _x^{\infty}t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$, so you can use it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$c_n:=\int_1^\infty x^n e^{-x}\>dx\qquad(n\geq 0)\ .$$
Then $c_0={1\over e}$, and
$$c_n=-x^n e^{-x}\biggr|_1^\infty+n\int_1^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x}\>dx={1\over e}+ n c_{n-1}\qquad(n\geq1)\ .$$
We shall only need $c_1={2\over e}$ and $c_2={5\over e}$. Now your integral
$$J:=\int_1^\infty\int_1^\infty(x+y)^2 e^{-(x+y)}\>dy\>dx$$
can be decomposed into
$$J=c_2c_0+2c_1^2 +c_0c_2={18\over e^2}\ ,$$
because
$$\int_1^\infty\int_1^\infty x^p e^{-x}\> y^q e^{-y}\>dy\>dx=c_p\>c_q\ .$$
The solution to your original problem is then $$A={e^2\over 18}\ .$$

Comment: Thx! Today I think I have some idea how to solve it by using polar http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf       r can actually be integrated to infinite. But your derivation is good.